# drupal 7 - multilingual (home page not showing in French language)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have implemented Multilingual in one of my drupal project at localhost and I have created one additional language i.e. French. However, on clicking the French link on the front end, (http://localhost/drupal71/fr), the home page is not showing, instead its showing a message :

Aucun contenu de page d'accueil n'a été créé pour l'instant.

No content homepage has been created yet. (translation of the above message in English).

I have created the home page and linked it with Main Menu. Accessing by http://localhost/drupal71 is working fine (in English default), however, http://localhost/drupal71/fr is showing the message as mentioned above.

Awaiting your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the node you are using as homepage and trying to access has only English version. That is the reason you see the message "No content has been created yet". If you want to display the exact same content for both languages you could set it to "language neutral". However if you want to display a French version of it you should translate it. This is done from the "Translate" tab you will see in the node edit form of your page.